# Как получить webhooks отдаваемые в формате json?

Tags: php, json

```
$data = file_get_contents('php://input');
if ($data) 
  file_put_contents(
    'unisender/status.txt',
    ' php://input ',
    FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
if (!$data) 
  file_put_contents(
    'unisender/status.txt',  
    ' NOT php://input ', 
    FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
```

Сервис `Unisender` передаёт по API c помощью `webhooks` события по рассылкам в формате json. 
Вышеуказанный скрипт записывает в файл по всем событиям `"NOT php://input"`, то есть не получает данные через `php://input`.

Как получить `webhooks` отдаваемые в формате json?

Answer (score 1):

Пример поддержки:

```
    class hook {
       public
       function handle($receiver_path) {
           $filename = basename($receiver_path, '.php');

           $api_key = "'';// ваш api_key 

           $postData = file_get_contents('php://input');
           if (strlen($postData) > 0) {
               $decodedData = json_decode($postData, true);
               if ($decodedData == '') {
                   $decodedData = json_decode(gzdecode($postData), true);
               }
               $hash = $decodedData['auth'];
               $decodedData['auth'] = $api_key;
               file_put_contents('/tmp/__'.$filename.
                   '__'
                   .time().
                   '.log', var_export($decodedData, true)
                   .
                   "nn Hash received: {$hash}n Hash verifying: "
                   .md5(json_encode($decodedData)));
           } else {
               $actual_link = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_U RI]";
               file_put_contents('/tmp/GET__'.$filename.
                   '__'
                   .time().
                   '.log', $actual_link, FILE_APPEND);
               echo 'Yep! It works! Filename: '.$filename;
           }
       }
   }
```

Из него видно что может приходить пустой хук.

Также вероятно на старых версиях так как нам не приходит хидер с multi-part/form-data, может быть что ввод пустой: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20148962/5892568

Поэтому возможно может помочь: http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.enable-post-data-reading

> При отключении этой опции суперглобальные переменные $_POST и $_FILES
>   не будут заполняться. Единственным способом прочесть POST-данные будет
>   чтение обертки потока php://input. Это может оказаться полезным при
>   проксировании запросов или обработки POST-данных способом, более
>   эффективно использующим память.

Comment: с поддержкой переписывался, с хостингом всё в порядке. Никто не может сказать почему данные не приходят или как их принять. При этом метод POST получает данные.                     `if (isset($_POST) && !empty($_POST)) 
{
file_put_contents('unisender/status.txt', ' post ', FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
}`

Comment: Думаю надо смотреть:

Comment: какая версия PHP и в каком окружении запускается... apache, php_fpm. предположу что у вас каконить denver/с старым php?